# View does have variables I do not pass to it

Tags: ajax, laravel, view, parameters

I do an ajax call and I have this code in the controller:

```
$menu = view('partials.nav_reserved_area', $data)->render();
return response()->json(['reserved_menu' => $menu]);
```

If I print $data variable before the render, this is what I get:

```
    array:12 [▼
        "request_url" => "https://www.example.com"
        "theatre_events" => Collection {#515 ▼
            #items: []
        }
        "music_events" => Collection {#498 ▼
            #items: []
        }
        "others_events" => []
    ]
```

As You can see "theatre_events" and "music_events" are empty collection.
I do not why, but in the view, "theatre_events" and "music_events" have some items, as if it gets data from another ajax call or from another part of code.
How is it possible?

**UPDATED**

This should be the code incriminated (the other part of the code where maybe view gets data):

```
Model::whereHas('event', function ($query) {
            $query
                ->where('end', '>=', \Carbon\Carbon::today())
                ->where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->where('event_type', 'theatre');
        })->paginate(20);
```

Comment: possibly lazy loaded eloquent models?

Comment: how can I see that? and how can I do not do that?

Comment: Paste the code of where $data came from. It looks like you are eager-loading relationships collections to that array.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Got it. I had forgotten I created a view composer where I set those variables. Thanks for the help to all.